# Configuring lidR catalog to save files with same filename?

Tags: r, lidar, save, lidr, catalog-service

I'm trying to learn how to use the options of `catalog()` within the `lidR` package in R. I'd like to save directly the processed files, for example, using grid_terrain() function over a catalog and save files keeping the filename of the original LAZ/LAS file.

As you can see in the [guide of the package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/lidR.pdf), catalog has the option of save the file using things like `{XBOTTOM}_{ID}`:

```
# Internal engine will not return results into R. Instead it will write results in files.
opt_output_files(ctg) <- "/path/to/folder/templated_filename_{XBOTTOM}_{ID}
```

I'd like to save the files using the same filename, but, I don't know how to configure that part with `{}` in the `opt_output_files()` option. I tried several things like, for instance: `opt_output_files(cat) <- paste0(output,"/{data$filename}")` but, it doesn't work.

```
lasdir <- "C:/lazfiles"
output <- "C:/output"

cat <- catalog(lasdir)
lasfiles <- cat@data$filename #with this you can see the filenames
opt_progress(cat) <- TRUE
opt_output_files(cat) <- paste0(output,"/{data$filename}")
opt_cores(cat) <- 3
opt_chunk_buffer(cat) <- 20

#function that I want to use over the catalog files
mdt <- grid_terrain(cat, res = 5, algorithm = knnidw(k = 5, p = 2))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer in the `grid_terrain` help section "supported processing options":

> output_files: Return the output in R or write each cluster’s output in a file. Supported templates are ... , ORIGINALFILENAME.

This is the solution:

```
opt_output_files(cat) <- paste0(output,"/{ORIGINALFILENAME}")
```